# SQL Eliminate Duplicate Row Based On Two Columns

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Trying to write a Presto query to eliminate what I'm considering duplicate entries. Here's a simplified version of my table:

| colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BB | CC |
| BB | AA | CC |
| DD | EE | FF |
| AA | DD | GG |

If there are rows where colA and colB contain an inverse duplicate, I want to exclude one from my query results (i.e. where we have (AA, BB) and (BB, AA), so I'd get:

| colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BB | CC |
| DD | EE | FF |
| AA | DD | GG |

It doesn't really matter if I keep the (AA, BB) or (BB, AA) pairing, for this purpose, they're the same. The actual values are semi-random strings.

I've tried a number of approaches like trying NOT EXISTS and different JOINs, but they end up removing both (AA, BB) and (BB, AA) rows.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use window functions:

```
select a, b, c
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by least(a, b), greatest(a, b), c order by c) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Another method would use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where a < b or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.c = t.c and
                        t2.b = t.a and
                        t2.a = t.b
                 );
```

To be honest, I don't have a sense of which would perform better on Presto.

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` approach doesn't work when I just tried it. I still get duplicate rows. The simplified example only has 3 columns, but in reality, it could be hundreds, but I'm only concerned with `colA` and `colB` as far as duplicate values go.

Comment: @mhaken . . . Are you sure you are comparing b to a in each table?

Comment: Hmm, I must have had a typo, retyped it and I think it works now.